# Is smelling impure things (like pig) haram?

Tags: halal-haram, najis

Is it possible that air could contain impurities?
If the air do contain impurities, would it be haram to breath in that air?

As an example when you pass by a pork market, it smells pork (and pork is impure), **does that imply that even the smell of the pork is haram?**

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Ask about passing by an alcohol distillation factory, it can actually make you drunk to breathe alcohol vapors. For a pork market, it doesn't look quite the same  (and I never saw a market only for pork).

Comment: @user5751924 Have you got some source? Never saw this in any Muslim texts, and never meet someone who get drunk only by the air.

Comment: @PEIRCE-NEIGE It can even be a business, I will have to try this https://www.wired.com/2015/08/brilliant-bar-gets-drunk-alcoholic-cloud/  Do you also want a medical study ?

Comment: It has nothing to see with the topic!  it's intentional inhaling of booze, not really the same...And the site is not really... medical. Yes, medical studies are better, when they applied. Do you know you can become drunk by eating fruit + sugar on an empty stomach, and animals often become drunk by eating ripe fruit?

Answer (score 1):

Please, see [here](http://www.prayerinislam.com/purification-2/purification-types-of-impurities-12/) for instance for  a sum up of the different kind of impurities in Islam:

- Dead animals (direct contact and consuming)
- Impure animals (same thing)
- Blood
- Impure products of the human body (urine, feces, etc...)

I may be ignorant, but I know about contact and consuming, but I never saw anything in the texts about the surrounding air, and the required distance.